# iOS App Store keyword search has no results

Tags: ios, app-store

I've already contacted Apple and am waiting for a reply, but I'm antsy.

My iOS app was approved and ready for sale on May 30 and from then through last night (June 1st), I was able to find my app via searching 'keyword' or 'keyword Foo'. I now can't find it via 'keyword'. I can still find it via 'Foo' or any of my other keywords (I have 5 in all), but if I search 'kewyord Foo' there are no results. If I search 'keyword' by itself there are about 15 other results, but my app is not listed.

Has this happened to you before? Did it get resolved? Any kind of insight would be helpful.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the functionality of Apple's App Store and not about programming.

Comment: I put up an app (not my main project), and searching the exact name of it, it came up 20th in the results. A week later, it dropped much further down.

Comment: @9000, that's not the issue I'm experiencing. My app is not found via the keyword at all. I re-checked and there are exactly 27 results for the keyword that's not working. My app is not one of them although I have it as a keyword in my metadata

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyword that was NOT working was another company's name which is why it wasn't working.

Additionally, the documentation regarding that was contradictory, but I can't remember what document said you can't use another company's name. Also, an Apple rep told me that was why.